# Renaming characters based on condition in R

Tags: r, rename, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a dataset containing state-level information. The df comes with the states named as "Alabama - statewide," "Alaska - statewide", etc. I'd like to drop the "statewide" from each variable name in the state column. My below attempt isn't working:

```
    library(tm)
    
    stopwords = "Statewide"
    
    BLS_wages_1982 <- BLS_wages_1982 %>% 
    removeWords(str,stopwords)
```

[image]

Comment: You can `separate` and then drop second column

Comment: This worked great, ty! BLS_wages_1982_2018 <- BLS_wages_1982_2018 %>% 
  separate(state, c("state", "statewide"), sep="--")

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub`, for a base R option:

```
df$area_title <- sub("\\s+--\\s+Statewide$", "", df$area_title)
```